# Excel Countifs - Search Text in String

Tags: excel, search, formula, countif

I have a column (let's say B1) in an Excel form that shows some products like this:

```
Sand Systems
Gas Systems
Blenders
Other
Other 2
Other 3
Other 4
```

I need to count the rows that doesn't contain the text "Other #" (# being a number), in other words, "Sand Systems", "Gas Systems", "Blenders" and "Other" = 4.

The solution so far was using an auxiliary column with the formula `=SEARCH` , but how to make it ignore the "Other" cell and accept "Other #"? Additionally, I wouldn't like to use an auxiliary column, but a cell with the `=COUNTIF` formula. Any advice?

Comment: By "Excel form", I don't mean USERFORM. It's only that this column is standard for all other products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is something like:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A7,"<>" & "Other *")
```

This returns 4, which is the expected result?

Using the whole column reference *will* return the incorrect result, just FYI.  If you're dead set on using whole column references use Ron Rosenfeld's formula:

```
=COUNTA(A:A)-COUNTIF(A:A,"Other *")
```

Comment: Counted only once, using only formula logic. Amazing.

Answer (score 1):

```
=COUNTA(A:A)-COUNTIF(A:A,"Other *")
```

Count them all, then subtract the one's that contain Other followed by space and anything else.

Comment: Both answers are fine but this is preferable as it looks at the entire column rather than a brittle hard coded range.

Comment: @Zerk you know the range is there just as an example. It works with whole column references.  And not taking anything away from this, why have excel count twice when it doesn't have to?

Comment: @Sous2817 Now that you have edited your answer to look at the entire column it gives an incorrect result (Test it). Hence me upvoting Ron's answer.

Comment: @Zerk.  ha!  Foot meet mouth :) I've rolled it back to at least give the correct answer.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @sous2817 As your answer was accepted by the question raiser then anyone googling for a similar problem will likely take your solution, for the sake of people getting appropriate solutions please add Ron's answer to yours.

Comment: @Zerk  done and done and hopefully attributed properly.  Hopefully that will get rid of that pesky -1.

Comment: @sous2817 =abs(-1)